# How to migrate or export just only eperson's (users) in dspace?

Tags: content-management-system, user-experience, dspace

Is it possible to migrate or export just the users(epersons) in the same way as the items and collections / communities via the application or command line without having to import all the dspace content?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following process might help.  Test carefully if you decide to follow this approach.

Using the [AIP export command](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC5x/AIP+Backup+and+Restore), you can export a site object without exporting all of the descendant communities and collections.  This will create an XML representation of your users and groups.

```
dspace packager -d -t AIP -e user@yourdomain.org -i XXX/0 aip_file
```

I do not know if this will meet your needs.  I have used this process to transfer users and groups into an empty test repository.

Comment: I used this command with the parameter 'k' which checks if there are already registered users in the database and it jumps to the next users, so it does not overwrite the already registered users.

This is very useful because if you need to migrate partial records of the dspace, without migrate all content dspace in my case, the users(eperson). thanku!